# jQuery Mobile .toggle() not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm currently using jQuery Mobile and simply wish to hide and show certain divs every time I click on a button. Here is my code:

```
$('#SignUpLink').click(function() 
            {
                    $('#signinputup').toggle('normal',function() {
                      $('#signinput').hide('fast');
                    }, function() {
                      $('#signinput').show('fast');
                    });
            });
```

I simlply want to click on the `SignUpLink` button and want the `signinput` to appear and make `signinput` disappear and then when I click on `SignUpLink` I want the inverse to happen. But with the given code above I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'function () {
                      $('#signinput').hide('fast');
                    }' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

I'm not sure what the error means and how to fix the code to obtain the functionality I'm looking for

Comment: jquery version? beware `.toggle()` changed as from 1.8

Comment: I'm using one of the latest versions of jQuery 1.9.x

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zbjZu/1/

Comment: @Omar so close just when you click on the button Test 1 disappears and then when you click on the button again Test 2 disappears and Test 1 reappears

Comment: this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/zbjZu/3/

Comment: @Omar Never fail to disappoint! Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, just make sure the second element is hidden beforehand

```
$('#SignUpLink').click(function() {
    $('#signinput, #signinputup').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [syntax](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) of the `toggle` function. It has four different ways of call:

1. Two parameters:

   ```
    .toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )
   ```

   Where `duration` is a number or string and `complete` a function.
2. One parameter:

   ```
    .toggle( options )
   ```

   Where `options` is a object with the configuration.
3. Three parameters:

   ```
    .toggle( duration [, easing ] [, complete ] )
   ```

   Where `easing` is a string.
4. One parameter:

   ```
    .toggle( showOrHide )
   ```

   Where `showOrHide` is a boolean.

In your code you are calling with **three** parameters, which is **wrong** because it doesn't match with any of this:

```
 $('#signinputup').toggle('normal', /*ONE*/
                   function() {$('#signinput').hide('fast');}, /*TWO*/
                   function() {$('#signinput').show('fast');}  /*THREE??*/
 );
```

Comment: I've tried using your code, but I seem to still keep getting the same problem. I've made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbjZu/

Comment: @user1638809 Read again the post, I am telling what is wrong, change your code according your needs

Comment: @koala_dev I didn't post the correct code because the question is not clear enough.